# Significant differences between NPT and NVT equilibrated simulations

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, forcefields

I am performing a set of classical MD simulations using a type of ReaxFF description to study aluminate Oligomerization. I have performed two sets of simulations, one where the system is equilibrated only using an NVT ensemble, and the other where the system is equilibrated using both NPT and NVT ensembles. I observed that the results obtained from NVT equilibrated simulations are significantly different from the ones that were obtained from NPT+NVT equilibrated systems. Interestingly, the box dimensions did not change significantly between these runs, with the initial box length of 15 angstroms relaxing to 15.75 angstroms after the NPT equilibration. Any pointers as to why is this happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: What results are you looking at? A change of 0.75 A in a 15 A lattice is 5%, so it's not a negligible change and to maintain the temperature you might have to pump in quite a bit of energy.

Comment: I am looking at the alumina coordination numbers, and NVT results give an expected trend in coordination numbers (should become progressively hexa-coordinated as concentration increases), but NPT results say that alumina stays as tetra-coordinated.

Comment: Well if you decrease the pressure by increasing the box size it seems to me that keeping a lower coordination number is not very surprising. My guess is that you have to specify a but more carefully quite exactly what you are trying to simulate.

Comment: I am studying the nucleation of aluminate ions forming gibbsite.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by NPT+NVT?

Comment: I first do an NPT equilibration followed by an NVT equilibration.